# Add Token to headers request in TEST mode DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, testcase, django-tests

how is possible to add `'Authorization': 'Token'` to TEST request in Django/DRF?

If i use simple `requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Token'}` all work perfect but how to do such request in TestCase?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#credentialskwargs

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

# Include an appropriate `Authorization:` header on all requests.
token = Token.objects.get(user__username='lauren')
client = APIClient()
client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
```

Comment: Thank dude, this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for multiple headers in your Django test cases, you can use the following code as an example:

```
HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_PROXY_SECRET = '<value>'
HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_HOST = '<value>'
TEST_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION = '<value>'
HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_SUBSCRIPTION = '<value>'

class YourTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(
            username='testuser',
            email='test@test.com',
            password='password',
            subscription=self.subscription
        )
        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        self.user.save()
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.headers = {
            'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f'{self.token.key}',
            'HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_HOST': HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_HOST,
            'HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_PROXY_SECRET': HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_PROXY_SECRET,
            'HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_SUBSCRIPTION': HTTP_X_RAPIDAPI_SUBSCRIPTION
        }
        self.client.credentials(**self.headers)

    def test_your_view(self):
        response = self.client.get('/your-url/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # Add your assertions here
```